# How do I exclude a few columns from a DataFrame plot?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with about 25 columns, several of which hold data unsuitable for plotting.  DataFrame.hist() throws errors on those.  How can I specify that those columns should be excluded from the plotting?

Answer (score 26):

Note, a modification to @Chang She's response, as of pandas 0.16, the `-` operator is scheduled for deprecation.  The `difference()` method is encouraged in its place.

```
exclude = ['bad col1', 'bad col2']
df.loc[:, df.columns.difference(exclude)].hist()
```

---

Update on [deprecation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/dsintro.html#data-alignment-and-arithmetic):

> ```
> df - df['A']
> ```
>
> is now deprecated and will be removed in a future release. The
>   preferred way to replicate this behavior is
>
> ```
> df.sub(df['A'], axis=0)
> ```

Answer (score 10):

I imagine you could just:

```
df.drop(['bad col1', 'bad col2', 'bad col3', ...], axis=1).hist()
```

Answer (score 8):

We can potentially make this easier (I created a [github issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2099)), but for now you can select out the columns you want to plot:

```
df.ix[:, df.columns - to_exclude].hist()
```

Comment: what is the "to_excl" object?

Comment: As a "to_excl" object, you can use a list with column names to exclude.

Answer (score 6):

I usually do the following:

```
columns = [column for column in df.columns if df[column].dtype == 'float64']
df = df[columns]
```

Answer (score 4):

Following the official [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/10min.html) you can use loc

```
df.loc[:,['A','B']]
```

And you obtain, for instance, only the column 'A' and 'B'.
In this way you can select the columns to plot.

Comment: this isn't an exclude as the OP wanted

Answer (score 0):

How about just

```
df_new = df[df.columns -[cols_to_exclude]]
df_new.plot()
```