# tPlotting scatter_matrix with selected columns from panda dataframe using scatter_matrix(dataset)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I referred to this question first (but I want a scatter matrix ):

[How do I exclude a few columns from a DataFrame plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003051/how-do-i-exclude-a-few-columns-from-a-dataframe-plot)

But instead of excluding columns, I want to include 4 columns from a list of around 25. And since the columns I intend to choose aren't nearby, slicing could be a hassle too.

For example: Let's say this is my header list:

```
['x1', 'x2', 'y1', 'y2', 'url', 'type', 'token', 'slotId', 'distance',     'workerId', 'projectId', 'timestamp', 'scheduleId', 'timeEntryId', 'endTimestamp', 'browserVersion', 'scheduleEndTime', 'scheduleStartTime', 'x', 'y', 'btn', 'keyType', 'taskId', 'url_domain']
```

And I want the scatter_matrix of  x1,y1, yrl,distance,timestamp and taskId.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you add data sample with desired output for plot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass only those selected columns in that function:

```
scatter_matrix(dataset_name[['x1','y1','yrl','distance','timestamp','taskId']])
```